# could not excute query in MariaDB

Tags: php, database, mariadb

Hello every one i am trying to update the product table in my database 
the user must enter the id of the product to make the update 
this is the form

```
            <form id="myform"method="post"action="update.php">
        <table class="userinf">
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">PID</label></td>
                <td><input id ="edtxt" class ="itxt"type="text" name="PID"required></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Name</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt1" class ="itxt"type="text" name="Name" r></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Picture</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt2" class ="itxt" type="text" name="Picture" ></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Price</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt3" class ="itxt" type = "text" name="Price" pattern="[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Type</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt4" class ="itxt" type="text" name="Type"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="labelii">Stock</label></td>
                <td><input id ="iitxt5" class ="itxt"type="number" name="Stock"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="Ebutton" onclick="submitform()">Update All</button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

this is the php code that make the update , the query i toke it from the DB

```
            <?php
        if(isset($_POST['PID'])){
            $PID=$_POST['PID'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST["Name"]) && isset($_POST["Picture"]) && isset($_POST["Price"]) && isset($_POST["Type"]) && isset($_POST["Stock"])){
            $Name=$_POST['Name'];
            $Picture=$_POST['Picture'];
            $Price=floatval($_POST['Price']);
            $Type=$_POST['Type'];
            $Stock=intval($_POST['Stock']);
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Name` = '$Name' , `Picture` = '$Picture', `Price` = '$Price' ,`Type` = '$Type' ,`Stock` = '$Stock' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Name'])){ 
            $Name=$_POST['Name'];
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Name` = '$Name' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['Picture'])){
            $Picture=$_POST['Picture'];
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Picture` = '$Picture' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
        else if( isset($_POST['Price'])){
            $Price=floatval($_POST['Price']);
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Price` = '$Price' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['Type'])){
            $Type=$_POST['Type'];
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Type` = '$Type' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
        else if(isset($_POST['Stock'])){
            $Stock=intval($_POST['Stock']);
            $query="UPDATE `product` SET `Stock` = '$Stock' WHERE `product`.`PID` = '$PID'";
        }
```

**this the last version of my code it only update the name**

Comment: Also note that it's the database itself returning that error, so when it says "line 1" it's not talking about your code, it's talking about line 1 of the statement you are attempting to run.

Comment: how could i know which statement its running , because when the code start to run it is only changes the name of the product ido not know why

Answer (score 0):

It is just DB API error return from the DB server, nothing to do with you code language. It indicate that you pass invalid SQL statement.

There is an extra coma  "," before WHERE statement in your first $query assignment statement.

Update : zainab, I see your editing, now, is the original problem solved?

Comment: i toke the query from the database it self i just replace values with php variables

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST["Name"]` is, say, `O'Brian`, you will get a syntax error.  Escape anything that comes from a `<form>`.